# Updating cost from one table to another

Tags: sql

I need a script to update costs from `VENINV` to `STOCK`

```
STOCK 
Stk_Invno=sku
Stk_cost=cost

VENINV
Vin_Invno=sku
Vin_cost=cost
```

I need to update the cost in `VENINV` to `STOCK`
I need the cost to be the highest cost found for the sku in `VENINV` to update 
the cost for all matching sku records in Stock
How do I join and update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to accomplish you can try

```sql
UPDATE Stock
SET Stk_cost = 
(SELECT MAX(Vin_cost) 
   FROM VENINV 
  WHERE Vin_Invno = Stk_Invno)
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89547/1) SQLServer

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for ? Did I understood you correctly ?

```
update T1
set T1.Field = T2.Field
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2 on T1.SomeId = T2.SomeJoiningId
```

Or In your case, it should be:

```
UPDATE STOCK
SET STOCK.Stk_Cost = VENINV.Vin_Cost
FROM STOCK
INNER JOIN VENINV.Vin_Invno = STOCK.Stk_Invno
```

Comment: Update STOCK
set stock.stk_cost= VENINV.VIN_COST
from VENINV.VIN_COST
inner join STOCK on stock.STK_INVNO = VENINV.VIN_INVNO   Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Well, yes - more or less, this will update STOCK.STK_COST and will set it to VENINV.VIN_COST. NOTE: make sure that your join is correct - I mean the field, STK_INVNO = VIN_INVNO, is this a field that you can join the tables on ? If yes, that that's your query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
update STOCK 
set Stk_cost = isnull((select top (1) v.Vin_cost from VENINV v 
where v.Vin_Invno = Stk_Invno),Stk_cost)
```

I have checked it and this works fine.